# Perl scraping script not recognising certain characters

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have a script that works fine locally but on the server fails.

It displays the  non-breaking space symbol

```
&nbsp;
```

as

```
?
```

when printing to standard output.

In the parsing of the page, if I try to get rid of non breaking space symbol with

```
s/\&nbsp\;//g
```

nothing happens, neither getting rid of the question mark

```
s/\?//g
```

It seems to stick no matter what.

Bizzarely, this is not an issue when running the script locally.

However, an issue on both local machine and server is that apostrophes (represented in the HTML I am scraping as an acute symbol

```
&acute;
```

are always represented as a question mark

```
?
```

even if explicitly trying

```
s/&acute;/'/g
```

Confused, pls help.

Comment: It is pretty difficult to understand what you are doing. Post the relevant code (a reduced example of the problem)

Comment: Also add the output of `locale` from the server and the local machine.

Comment: You don't have to escape "&" and ";", only meta-characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will try to remove it like this:

**No-break space**

```
my $non_break_space = "\x{A0}";
$non_break_space =~ s/\xA0/ /g;
```

**Acute accent**

```
my $acute = "\x{B4}";
$acute =~ s/\xB4/ /g;
```

You can use this site [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm) for get more information about unicode characters and their different values.

Comment: Great, this works to remove the non-breaking space problem.  However, the apostrophe issue - represented by    &acute; remains (original question above has been edited to include this).

Comment: That has solved the problem - thanks.  Not sure I understand what is going on with unicode, will have to read up about it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question with [mojolicious](/questions/tagged/mojolicious), I assume you're working with [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us). Try to run this test script on your server and show us the results:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use utf8;
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Test::More tests => 3;
use Test::Mojo;

get '/test_html' => {text => "<p>Hello&nbsp;&nbsp;World&acute;!</p>"};
my $t = Test::Mojo->new;

$t->get_ok('/test_html')->status_is(200)->text_is('p', 'Hello World´!');
```

Works fine here:

```
1..3
ok 1 - get /test_html
ok 2 - 200 OK
ok 3 - exact match for selector "p"
```

Comment: Hi, I get the correct output back from the test as follows:   1..4
ok 1 - get /test_html
ok 2 - 200 OK
ok 3 - exact match for selector "p"
ok 4 - right space.

Comment: However, the problem still remains with the script that apostrophes are not picked up for some reason.

Comment: Correction for apostrophe problem:  The HTML has &acute; for the apostrophe. This is represented as a question mark and not an apostrophe.

Comment: Hi - so if I change your example text to include the problem apostrophe (I realise it's an 'acute' symbol but it's representing a name, like O'Reilly), I get this:   #  Change text string <p>Hello&nbsp;&nbsp;World&acute;s!</p>  Now, run the script and print out your test output:1..4
ok 1 - get /test_html
ok 2 - 200 OK
not ok 3 - exact match for selector "p"
#   Failed test 'exact match for selector "p"'
#   at test line 10.
#          got: 'Hello World?s!'
#     expected: 'Hello World!'
ok 4 - right space
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 4.
That sums up the problem - World?s not World's

Comment: I updated the answer - works fine with `&acute;` too. Note that I had to `use utf8` to tell perl that the code is UTF-8-encoded.

Comment: Thanks that test works.  Interestingly the site is using    &acute;  instead of an apostrophe, so the answer above is what is needed in this case - ie.      $acute =~ s/\xB4/'/g;